# Webpack rename require.ensure generated chunks

Tags: angularjs, webpack

Is there any way to rename generate chunks using require.ensure?
I want a more descriptive name like home.js instead of 1.1.js.

My code:

```
require.ensure([], () => {
  let module = require('../home');
  $ocLazyLoad.load({name: 'home'});
  resolve(module.controller);
});
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third param of `require.ensure` is name:

```
require.ensure([], () => {
  ...
}, "chunk");
```

From [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html#require-ensure):

```
require.ensure(dependencies: String[], callback: function([require]), [chunkName: String])
```

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed that part of documentation. I'll try to go deeper next time.